# alternating series test 5

Tags: calculus

I have to find the convergence of this sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\ln(n)$$

I tried the alternating sum test, but the terms are decreasing. What test should I use instead?

Comment: Is it $\sum_{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}$?

Comment: If it is $\sum (-1)^n \ln n$, easy divergence, the terms don't have limit $0$.

Comment: Yes, it's this. The original series was power series sum(0, infinity) lnn*x^n, and i got hat by checking its left endpoint -1.

Comment: The sum should really not start at $0$, since $\ln 0$ is undefined. But if we start at $1$, the original series is convergent if $|x|\lt 1$ and divergent if $|x|\ge 1$.

Comment: Yes, but i have to check the endpoints too for the interval of convergence: -1 and 1

Comment: Certainly, and we did, the terms do not have limit $0$ at $x=-1$ and at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. As a consequence, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ does not exist, or is anything but $0$, then $\sum_N^\infty a_n$ does not converge.

For your particular series, we should not start at $n=0$, since $\ln 0$ is undefined.

The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n \ln n$ does not exist, so $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^n \ln n$ does not converge.